# VARCHAR SQL contains numbers how to get 2 decimals after comma

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm having some trouble getting the price to show correct on my website. Currently i have a row `VerkoopPP40` which is a `VARCHAR` input. In this row there is a price e.g. `89,5` or just `9`. When I try to get these values it does some unexpected things.

**** Update ****

I've just tried this code:

```
<?php
function formatNumber($number, $format=[], $oldDecimalSeparator=",.·'", $multiplier=1)
{

    if ($format) {
        $format += ['numOfDecimals' => 0, 'decimalSeparator' => '.', 'thousandSeparator' => '']; # Default format
        # Find decimal separator
        # The decimal separator is the one that is the last and does not occur more than once
        if ($letters = str_replace(' ', '', $number)) { # Replace spaces
            if ($letters = preg_replace('/^-/', '', $letters)) { # Remove minus
                if ($letters = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $letters)) { # Get all non digits
                    $lastletter = substr($letters, -1); # Returns last char
                    if (substr_count($letters, $lastletter) == 1) {
                        if (strpos($oldDecimalSeparator, $lastletter)  !== false)
                            $oldDecimalSep = $lastletter;
                        else
                            return $number;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $number = preg_replace('/[^0-9-]/', '', $number); # Remove all non digits except 'minus'
        if ($oldDecimalSep)
            $number = str_replace($oldDecimalSep, '.', $number); # Format to float
        if ($multiplier != 1)
            $number = $number * $multiplier;
        # Convert float to new format
        $number = number_format($number,
            $format['numOfDecimals'],
            $format['decimalSeparator'],
            $format['thousandSeparator']
        ); 
    }
    return $number;   
}
```

This returns: 9,00 and `895,00` so the comma is in a different place right now. It's something I guess... Anyone got an idea to move the comma and remove a 0.

**** End Update ****

And echo-ed it like this:

```
<td><p>vanaf " . formatNumber($number, [
    'numOfDecimals' => 2,
    'decimalSeparator' => ',',
    'thousandSeparator' => '&nbsp;'
], ',.') . " p.p. <small>Excl btw</small></p></td>
```

If I just `echo` the `VerkoopPP40` row it returns: €89,5 or €9.

So I googled around some and found this:

```
$var = $row["VerkoopPP40"];
$var = ltrim($var, '0');
$foo = $var;
$prijzen = number_format($foo, 2, ',', '');
```

This turns the `.` into a `,`. But also returns €9,00 for the row that has `9` in it. But the strange thing is the row that has `89.5` in it now just returns €89,00. So somewhere in the code it rounds the numbers down.

Does anyone know how to get the price to show just €9,00 and €89,50 respectively.

I tried the following codes as well:

```
SELECT ROUND(VerkoopPP40,2) AS RoundedPrice
```

As database query. That didn't work.

```
$prijzen = CAST($prijzen as decimal(2,2));
```

Also didn't work. Any more ideas?

Comment: This is why you should choose the appropriate datatype. Monetary values should be stored in a `MONEY` or `DECIMAL` column.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I'm not the "owner" of this database. And for some reason it has to be VARCHAR. So, there is nothing I can do to fix that...

Comment: if you echo $row["VerkoopPP40"], what's outputed?

Comment: I just echo the VerkoopPP40 row it returns: 29.5 or 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this will help you, but found in the comments of the PHP doc : "To prevent the rounding that occurs when next digit after last significant decimal is 5 (mentioned by several people)..." [read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$num1 = "89,5";
$num2 = str_replace(',', '.', $num1);

$price = number_format($num2, 2, '.', '');

echo"[ $price ]";
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this code still gives `,00` if the last digit is .5. To bad...

Comment: some solution is given in the comments, have you tried any and what does it output ?

Answer (score 1):

you should use number_format but in the right way let me explain it to you
you tried this with 89.5

```
$prijzen = number_format($foo, 2, ',', '');
```

but this is written for 89,5 not for 89.5

```
//this will work for you 


    $var = $row["VerkoopPP40"];
    echo 'raw output from database is :'.$var;
    $var = $var / 10;
    echo 'after this step the number is :'.$var;        
    $var = number_format($var, 2, '.', '');
    echo 'after this step the number is :'.$var;
```

number_format(the input number, decimal places, 'the divider between whole numbers and decimals', '')

Comment: let me have a look in my code maybe i forgot something i have used this before

Comment: yes my answer outputs right did you remove this from your code$var = ltrim($var, '0');
$foo = $var; this will trim it to 0 decimals

Comment: Hi Gert, Yup... I removed all other $var's and only have the two you suggested...

Comment: and show me a example of where you want to remove the 0 thats very easy and i will edit my code and we can debug where is the problem

Comment: I would like to have the price show as 89,50 where it is now 895,00.. I hope its an easy fix...

Comment: I'll probably think I'm not doing this correct but using /10 makes it output 8,90 and if I do /1 it's back to normal rounded down to ,00...

Comment: Gert, thanks for your help! Awesome!! But User3801953 answer did the trick. I don't know why but it did...

Comment: Thanks for +1 and validating answser